# How to implement a user answer that will either start a loop again or end the program

Tags: c, scanf

The purpose of this code is to sum up to a number greater than zero and then ask the user if they want to sum another number. The summing part of the program works, but I can't seem to get the user input to work correctly. Any help or insight would be appreciated.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void)
{
    char * another;
    int start = 0;
    int x = 0;
    int Input=0;
    int sum = 0;
    do
    {
        printf("Please enter a number greater than zero to sum up to: \n");
        scanf("%d", &x);
        if(start<x)
            Input=1;
        else
            printf("The number needs to be greater than zero.\n");
    }
    while (Input ==0) ;

    while (start <= x) {
        sum += start;
        start++;

        if (start >x)
        {
            printf("The sum of the numbers 0 to %d is: %d \n" ,x , sum);
        }
        while (start >x)
        {
            printf("Would you like to sum another number? Y/N:");
            scanf("%s",another);
        }
    } while ((another =="y")||(another=="Y"));
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Note that marking your code with symbols that cause it to fail compilation make it hard to tell what is and isn't supposed to be there. For instance, did you intend for there to be a semicolon in `while ((start >x));`? You should properly format your code in your editor, and copy it directly here (not by hand!). Use comments to indicate important lines.

Comment: There are `while` loops and there are `do`...`while` loops. However, in one case, you seem to have a `while`...`while` loop, which does not exist (or make sense).

Answer (score 1):

There are quite a few things to address here.

---

`char *another` allocates no memory for a string to be placed. It is just an uninitialized pointer to memory, containing a garbage *value*. Utilizing this *value* in any way will invoke [Undefined Behavior](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/behavior).

You must allocate some memory if you want to store a string. The easiest way is on the *stack*, as a character [array](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/array):

```
char another[64];
```

---

Strings should not be compared with `==`, as that compares their addresses, which even for two identical literals ("a" == "a") might not be the same. Use [strcmp](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte/strcmp) to compare strings.

---

There is no `while ... while`.

```
while (start <= x) {
    /* ... */
} while ((another =="y")||(another=="Y"));
```

This is one `while` statement with a [Compound Statement](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/statements#Compound_statements) for a body, followed by another, separate `while` statement with an **empty** [Expression Statement](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/statements#Expression_statements) for a body.

More clearly read as:

```
while (start <= x) {
    /* ... */
}

while ((another =="y")||(another=="Y"));
```

It is of course possible to have a `do ... while` whose body is itself a `while` statement

```
do
    while (/* ... */) {
        /* ... */
    }
while (/* ... */);
```

but this is a bit confusing, and probably not what you really want.

---

The return value of `scanf` should be checked such that it matches the number of conversions you *expected* to succeed, in order to proceed to work with that data.

```
if (scanf("%d", &x) != 1) {
    /* Something has gone wrong, handle it */
}
```

Failure to check this value can result in using uninitialized or otherwise indeterminate data.

This is also where one of the major pitfalls of `scanf` occurs:

In the event that `scanf` cannot apply a conversion to the input stream, the data is left in the input stream, and `scanf` fails early. Your next call to `scanf` will read that same data unless it is purged first (usually accomplished by consuming characters until a newline or end-of-file is reached).

This is why it is generally advised to separate your *reading* and your *parsing* to gain more control. This can be achieved with [`fgets`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fgets) and [`sscanf`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fscanf), to first read a line of input, and then parse it.

The other option is to simply terminate the program on any failure, which is what I've done in the example below (for simplicity's sake).

Additionally note that `scanf("%s", buffer)` is vulnerable to overflowing `buffer`. Always limit your input using *field width specifiers*, in the form `scanf("%127s", buffer)`, which should be the length of your buffer minus one (leaving room for the NUL terminating byte).

---

Some things to consider:

- Allocate memory for your string buffer.
- Limit the amount of information that can be read into your buffer.
- Handle errors in some way.
- Use `continue` or `break` to help structure your flow.
- Use separate functions to clarify a common task.

An example:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int seqsum(int from, int to) {
    int sum = 0;

    while (from <= to)
        sum += from++;

    return sum;
}

int main(void) {
    char another[64];
    int working = 1;
    int n;

    while (working) {
        printf("Please enter a number greater than zero to sum up to: \n");

        if (scanf("%d", &n) != 1) {
            fprintf(stderr, "Invalid input or read error.\n");
            return 1;
        }

        if (n < 0) {
            printf("The number needs to be greater than zero. Retrying..\n");
            continue;
        }

        printf("The sum of the numbers 0 to %d is: %d\n", n, seqsum(0, n));
        printf("Would you like to sum another number? (y/n): ");

        if (scanf("%63s", another) != 1) {
            fprintf(stderr, "Invalid input or read error.\n");
            return 1;
        }

        working = (another[0] == 'y' || another[0] == 'Y');
    }
}
```

---

As an addendum, perhaps you were trying to read a single *character*?

Character constants are denoted by their enclosing single quotes (e.g., `'A'`), and can be compared with the `==` operator.

The `scanf` format specifier for a single character is `"%c"`. To skip leading white space (e.g., a [line feed](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Newline)), you can add a space before the format specifier: `" %c"`. The address of your `char` is given to `scanf` with the address-of operator (`&`).

```
char ch;

if (scanf(" %c", &ch) != 1) 
    /* failure */;
else if (ch == 'a' || ch == 'b')
    /* do something */;
```

Comment: Thank you for your help. I'm in an intro to C course and this is my only experience with coding so all I really know is what has been presented during lectures.